# React & Mapbox -> Map not interactive

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I can render my map with my style and private token however it isn't interactive (scroll, and move doesn't work) - Any ideas why? code below

```
import Map from 'react-map-gl'
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl-csp";
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function Map() {
const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    latitude: -33.932,
    longitude: 151.237,
    zoom: 12,
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 2,
    });

    return (
    <ReactMapGL
        mapStyle='mapbox://styles/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        mapboxAccessToken={process.env.mapbox_key}
        {...viewport}
        onViewportChange={(nextViewport) => setViewport(nextViewport)}
    >
    </ReactMapGL> 
)}
export default Map
```

Screengrab of what I have rendering
[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out for anybody else that comes across this problem.

CHANGE:

onViewportChange={(viewport) => setViewport(viewport)}

to:

onMove={evt => setViewport(evt.viewport)}

for more information: https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/get-started/state-management